# Wifi not working?

Tags: wireless

I downloaded ubuntu dual boot with windows 10 on my dell xps13, but when I try to connect to wifi using ubuntu it says no network devices available, the wifi works when I use windows. Could I please have help accessing a wifi connection? Below are the commands I was told to add. Thanks

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  2
bnep                   20480  2
b43                   417792  0
mac80211              737280  1 b43
cfg80211              565248  2 b43,mac80211
snd_soc_sst_broadwell    16384  1
ssb                    65536  1 b43
snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm    90112  3 snd_soc_sst_broadwell
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm
snd_soc_sst_dsp        53248  1 snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
btusb                  45056  0
hid_multitouch         20480  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
bcma                   53248  1 b43
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_soc_rt286          36864  2 snd_soc_sst_broadwell
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
snd_soc_rl6347a        16384  1 snd_soc_rt286
snd_hda_intel          36864  2
snd_hda_codec         135168  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_soc_core          212992  4 snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm,snd_soc_sst_broadwell,snd_soc_ssm4567,snd_soc_rt286
snd_hda_core           73728  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
int3403_thermal        16384  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
soc_button_array       16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_rt286,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
elan_i2c               36864  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  2 dw_dmac,snd_soc_sst_dsp
snd                    81920  18 snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_soc_sst_haswell_pcm,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
8250_dw                16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
int3402_thermal        16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_pad               20480  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
intel_hid              16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_hid
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
mei_me                 36864  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           57344  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
usbhid                 49152  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
psmouse               126976  0
i915                 1208320  7
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   360448  8 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,usbhid
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: Do you use _direct connection_ also and does that work ?

Comment: My dell xps 13 does not have an ethernet port sorry

Comment: You can summary the code snippets in your question with the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2` and `rfkill list wifi`.  Furthermore run `lsmod` and add the output. Are you sure that you posted the entirely output of `rfkill list`? If Yes try  `sudo modprobe dell_wmi` and run `rfkill list wifi` again and let us know if the output changes.

Comment: Sorry im not to familer with all this, could I please have a step by step? Thanks

Comment: Sure, you know what I mean if I said code snippet? 1 step edit your question and delete every line with gray background color, run  `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2`, `rfkill list wifi` and `lsmod` in a terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: okay done, but nothing happened when I ran rfkill list wifi

Comment: Remove `sudo modprobe -r dell_laptop`. To avoid that the module get loaded after restart automatically add a entry to your blacklist echo "blacklist dell_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf